# Google GSON nested HashMaps deserialization

Tags: java, json, gson

In my current project i use GSON library in android, and i've faced a problem of nested Maps deserializtion. This is how initial json looks like

```
 {

"5":{
    "id":5,
    "name":"initial name",
    "image_url":"uploads/71d44b5247cc1a7c56e62fa51ca91d9b.png",
    "status":"1",
    "flowers":{
        "7":{
            "id":7,
            "category_id":"5",
            "name":"test",
            "description":"some description",
            "price":"1000",
            "image_url":"uploads/test.png",
            "status":"1",
            "color":"red",

        }
    }
  }
 }
```

And my pojo's

```
class Category {
long id;
String name;
String image_url;
HashMap<String,Flower> flowers;
}
```

And Flower class

```
class Flower {
long id;
String category_id;
String name;
String description;
String price;
String image_url;
String status;
}
```

But when i try to deserialize this objects, i can access nested hashmaps, the example code is

```
public class TestJson {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("2.txt"));
    HashMap<String,Category> map = gson.fromJson(br, HashMap.class);
    Collection<Category> asd = map.values();
            System.out.println(map.values());

       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This `gson.fromJson(br, HashMap.class);` tells to Gson that you want to deserialize to a Map of unknown value type. You would be tempted to specifiy something like `Map<String,Category>.class`, but you can not do this in Java so the solution is to use what they called TypeToken in Gson.

```
Map<String, Category> categoryMap = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<Map<String, Category>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Yes, i've missed TypeTokens in my code, after fixes all works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.. This is exactly what i am looking for since last half-an-hour :)