# How to read specific value from Nth level in one line of code in complex structured data

Tags: java, json, serialization, arraylist, gson

I'm getting the data which is structured as a sort of tree (figuratively speaking), with nested structure with any types and their names and values. I'm not sure if I am clear enough but this how data I'm receiving can look like - example:

```
customerId (Integer)
|__ listOfCoustomers (List)
    |__ first_name (String)
    |__ last_name (String)
    |__ birth_date (Date)
    |__ address (Address)
        |__ ccountry (String)
        |__ city (String)
        |__ street (String)
    |__ is_employed (Integer)
    |__ previous jobs (List)
        |__ job_title (Jobs)
            |__ job_description (String)
            |__ worked_from (Date)
            |__ worked_until (Date)
            |__ recieved_salary_in_currency (NameValuePair)
                |__ name (Decimal)
                |__ value (Sting)
    |__ group_id (Integer)
    |__ occupation (Occupations)
        |__ name (String)
        |__ year (NameValuePair)
            |__ name (String)
            |__ value (String)
        |__ description (String)
            |__ occupaction_place (String)
                |__ occupation_address (Address)
                    |__ city (String)
                        |__ occupation_sight (Integer)
                    |__ street (String)
...... and so on
```

This structure could easily be started after customerId as something other as List:

```
customerId (Integer)
|__ Customer (Object)
    |__ first_name (String)
    |__ last_name (String) 
....
```

I think you got the picture: I can recieve unlimited level of nods in this data structure, and they can consist of every type: List, Object, String, Integer, NameValuePair or something else - and there is no limitation when can some class type occur. I'm not receiving file, I recieve this in one big object. And I don't want to transform this into file and parse it through for example XML, because I think I don't have time to do that and I think this could be easily done when transforming into JSON.

Now, with this data set, when i read values in my java code it is pretty slow to read this to me. I'm getting this transformed into large List. My task is to get values of some data and store it in database. Now, with my approach, I must do for-loop much of data and correctly write and test to get real parent or child, and that is slow. For every list I must do for loop and be careful because my parent nodes are changeing and I can'g grab anything in single line. Also for every different nesting I must write similar, but not the same approach. And I managed to speed up this relatively, by writing custom method to grab data - but that just took me away 2 lines of code for grabbing some specific value. I don't have to grab every value from List objects, or every value from entire data set. But as I have to rely on this List and must check what is nested and what is not, everything is still show.

**So I was wondering, could I transform this entire data set to some for example JSON structure with for example; GSON or some other library? I would like to be able to read more easily value from for example 6th node in one line of code.** Currently, I can't to that because when I get to some list, I must do loop in it.

But I think some serialization of data or transformation to JSON could do the trick to be able to more easily grab some value for example, from 16th node, 1st node or any node I like.

I would like to write something like this (or similar, this is just idea) and get value from every specific object I want:

```
String obj = node1.node2.node3.node4....node16.getValue().toString();
```

I currently can't do that. At least I could not manage it. I thought I maybe would be able to get this with various deep Array native Java methods, but I could not figure it out (I'm not so new to Java). Maybe I can do it like this - maybe I don't need GSON?
I manage to get some values with .get("name") but after that, when it comes to some List, I must loop in it again. Seems to me transformation names and their values would be good approach.

How to avoid to read every specific value with for loop, and instead to read it in 1 line?

If I'm clear enough. Can it be done? **I would also need to show me solution in code.**

**Edit:** 
I figure out that I would still need to use loops when List types would come (I would still need to iterate it because size of list could be dynamic, so I would need to go item by item), but nevertheless, my question stands - can data be grabedd more elegantly? I would like to Eclipse to give me code completion methods from GSON or similar library to dynamicaly offer me after pressing the dot (.) - new level and then next level(s) (if any more exist).. and value at the end. That is what i meant by:

```
String obj = node1.node2.node3.node4....node16.getValue().toString();
```

Comment: Anyone? I would really appriciate help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google GSON nested HashMaps deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358350/google-gson-nested-hashmaps-deserialization)