# Gson serialization of dynamic list

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have the following JSON file:

https://www.mediamarkt.de/appconfiguration.json

which looks like this:

```
{
"configuration": {
"locales": [
{
"de_DE": {
"basket": "https://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelDisplayBasket?storeId=48353&langId=-3",
"search": "http://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelSearch?storeId=48353&langId=-3&searchProfile=onlineshop&query=%5B%5BQUERY%5D%5D&searchParams=",
....
}
}
],
```

I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create corresponding classes, which can be parsed correctly, but: the locale value **de_DE** can be different, meaning that the name could also be **en_EN**. The created class file contains:

```
@SerializedName("de_DE")
private List<de_DE> de_DE;
```

but I need it to be generic. What do I have to change to make this possible? Please note that for some countries even multiple locale values could be existant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't always rely/trust that generator: it **cannot** work with polymorphic JSON documents and fails for dynamic data structures. All you need is just maps.

#### Version 1

```java
final class Response_v1 {
    final Configuration_v1 configuration = null;
}
```

```java
final class Configuration_v1 {
    final List<Map<String, BasketSearch>> locales = null;
}
```

```java
// previously de_DE
final class BasketSearch {
    final URL basket = null;
    final URL search = null;
}
```

(By the way, that generator does not map URLs (neither `java.net.URL`, nor `java.net.URI`)).

Test it out:

```
try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43843300.class, "generic.json") ) {
    final Response_v1 response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Response_v1.class);
    for ( final Map<String, BasketSearch> localeMap : response.configuration.locales ) {
        for ( final Entry<String, BasketSearch> e : localeMap.entrySet() ) {
            final String locale = e.getKey();
            final BasketSearch basketSearch = e.getValue();
            System.out.println(locale);
            System.out.println("\tsearch=" + basketSearch.search);
            System.out.println("\tbasket=" + basketSearch.basket);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Version 2

I cannot know if your service does not change the response for locales, but they look "flattenable" to me.

```java
final class Response_v2 {   
    final Configuration_v2 configuration = null;    
}
```

```java
final class Configuration_v2 {
    @JsonAdapter(FlatLocaleToBasketSearchTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final Map<String, BasketSearch> locales = null;
}
```

Where the bound type adapter factories are implemented like these (there is an abstract class and the Template Method design pattern implementation, because that API probably can generate documents with similar structure elsewhere):

```java
abstract class AbstractFlatTypeAdapterFactory<V, R>
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    protected AbstractFlatTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    // Get a specific value type adapter    
    protected abstract TypeAdapter<V> getValueTypeAdapter(Gson gson);

    // Create a new result to accumulate the result into
    protected abstract R createResult();

    // Merge K/V and the result
    protected abstract void putIntoResult(String key, V value, R result);

    @Override
    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final TypeAdapter<V> valueTypeAdapter = getValueTypeAdapter(gson);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new FlatTypeAdapter(basketSearchTypeAdapter).nullSafe();
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private final class FlatTypeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<R> {

        private final TypeAdapter<V> valueTypeAdapter;

        private FlatTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<V> valueTypeAdapter) {
            this.valueTypeAdapter = valueTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final R value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public R read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final R result = createResult();
            // Consume [
            in.beginArray();
            // And for-each elements
            while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                // Consume {
                in.beginObject();
                // And for-each properties
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    // Accumulate
                    final String key = in.nextName();
                    final V value = valueTypeAdapter.read(in);
                    putIntoResult(key, value, result);
                }
                // Consume }
                in.endObject();
            }
            // Consume ]
            in.endArray();
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

And your case implementation of the above type adapter factory (looks pretty much a configuration, doesn't it?):

```
final class FlatLocaleToBasketSearchTypeAdapterFactory
        extends AbstractFlatTypeAdapterFactory<BasketSearch, Map<String, BasketSearch>> {

    // Gson can handle it itself    
    private FlatLocaleToBasketSearchTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    protected TypeAdapter<BasketSearch> getValueTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
        return gson.getAdapter(BasketSearch.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, BasketSearch> createResult() {
        return new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void putIntoResult(final String key, final BasketSearch basketSearch, final Map<String, BasketSearch> locales) {
        locales.put(key, basketSearch);
    }

}
```

Demo:

```java
try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43843300.class, "generic.json") ) {
    final Response_v2 v1Response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Response_v2.class);
    for ( final Entry<String, BasketSearch> e : v1Response.configuration.locales.entrySet() ) {
        final String locale = e.getKey();
        final BasketSearch value = e.getValue();
        System.out.println(locale);
        System.out.println("\tsearch=" + value.search);
        System.out.println("\tbasket=" + value.basket);
    }
}
```

Both versions produce the same result:

> de_DE
>   search=http://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelSearch?storeId=48353&langId=-3&searchProfile=onlineshop&query=%5B%5BQUERY%5D%5D&searchParams=
>   basket=https://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelDisplayBasket?storeId=48353&langId=-3

Comment: Version one is working fine, without the hassle of extra classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Update 1 :

We can achieve it using GSONs SerializedName alternate property.

These are the code snippets of what I tried :

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName(value = "en_EN", alternate = {"de_DE"})
    Person person;
}

public class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
}

public void convert(View view) {
        String json = "{\"de_DE\":{\"name\":\"Monish\",\"age\":\"24\"}}";
        //String json = "{\"en_EN\":{\"name\":\"Monish\",\"age\":\"24\"}}";
        Response response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
    }
```

### Original Answer :

I would suggest to change the JSON structure as below :

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "locales": [
            {
                "locale": "de_DE",
                "basket": "https://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelDisplayBasket?storeId=48353&langId=-3",
                "search": "http://www.mediamarkt.de/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MultiChannelSearch?storeId=48353&langId=-3&searchProfile=onlineshop&query=%5B%5BQUERY%5D%5D&searchParams="
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Instead of keeping the varying value(locale) as an JSONObject, change it to key-value pair.

Comment: Sadly, the JSON cannot be changed, but I totally agree, that this would be a much better structure

Comment: Okay. Need to think a way around.

Answer (score 1):

try..   `@SerializedName(value="de_DE", alternate={"en_EN"})` ..This may be resolve your issue

**Update 1**

vist [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358350/google-gson-nested-hashmaps-deserialization) link..

hashmap deserialization will solve this issue.. no matter what the  locale value (de_DE) is ..  hope this will resolve

Comment: I would like to not update anything in code, when more locales are added.

Answer (score -1):

your pojo look like below

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;


public class Example {

    @SerializedName("configuration")
    @Expose
    private Configuration configuration;

    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public class Configuration {

        @SerializedName("locales")
        @Expose
        private List<Locale> locales = null;

        public List<Locale> getLocales() {
            return locales;
        }

        public void setLocales(List<Locale> locales) {
            this.locales = locales;
        }

    }

    public class DeDE {

        @SerializedName("basket")
        @Expose
        private String basket;
        @SerializedName("search")
        @Expose
        private String search;

        public String getBasket() {
            return basket;
        }

        public void setBasket(String basket) {
            this.basket = basket;
        }

        public String getSearch() {
            return search;
        }

        public void setSearch(String search) {
            this.search = search;
        }

    }


    public class Locale {

        @SerializedName("de_DE")
        @Expose
        private DeDE deDE;

        public DeDE getDeDE() {
            return deDE;
        }

        public void setDeDE(DeDE deDE) {
            this.deDE = deDE;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, thanks. But this doesn't help me, because of course I have this file. I want it to be generic